# Slip nut wrench vs adjustable wrench

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I'm trying to tighten a slip joint zinc nut where a leak appears to be coming from. I found this particular wrench which seems to fit the bill (shown below and [here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Armour-Line-1-in-To-3-in-Adjustable-Plumbers-Slip-Nut-Wrench-RP77321/306699653?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CAll-Products%7CAll%7CAll%7CPLA%7C71700000014585962%7C58700001236285396%7C92700010802552406&gclid=CjwKCAjw1dzkBRBWEiwAROVDLPxHusmORPExF0crMktBrYDeL1NgmFkqVyL8xLQjTLjIib3HQUuGnBoCSE4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)). How is this tool better-suited for the job than a standard adjustable spanner/wrench?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a larger jaw opening compared to the handle length - so it can be used in confined spaces ie under sinks baths etc

An "ordinary" adjustable with that jaw opening may have a handle of 18" to 24" or more...

Answer (score 1):

[image]I bought one of these wrenches you show many years ago and have used it only once.  They are a pain to use but will get the job done. I prefer an adjustable pliers made by Crescent or Channellock. Some people call them  "tongue and groove pliers". but plumbers and fitters just call them Channellocks. Tradesmen that work with piping and plumbing have them in many sizes the most common being a 12" pair. These are mine

Comment: I see this one has teeth...is this really the right one for a nut that has edges? The nut I have is the one shown here: https://www.grainger.com/product/444J21?gclid=CjwKCAjw-OHkBRBkEiwAoOZql1-8391VDLs5K4VbpvqyPCww91q1CWQS-6USA7AQv1-dTGoZ5FLdzRoCk5kQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAjw-OHkBRBkEiwAoOZql1-8391VDLs5K4VbpvqyPCww91q1CWQS-6USA7AQv1-dTGoZ5FLdzRoCk5kQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!284618243466!!!g!510245615962!.